# Adding a new class to the page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, class

I am trying to programatically add a DIV with the class of `error_icon` to the page using jQuery. This is the HTML:

```
<div id="error_icon_holder"></div>
```

When they're added, the markup should resemble:

```
<div id="error_icon_holder">
    <div class="error_icon"></div>
</div>
```

I tried using `.addClass`, but that resulted in:

```
<div id="error_icon_holder" class="error_icon"></div>
```

And I also tried `.after` which also didn't work. Can someone let me know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `.append()`

```
$('#error_icon_holder').append('<div class="error_icon"></div>');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/append/

---

You could also flip it around, and use `.appendTo()`.

```
$('<div class="error_icon"></div>').appendTo('#error_icon_holder');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

---

Or since `error_icon_holder` appears to be empty, you could use `.html()`. (This would normally overwrite any existing content.)

```
$('#error_icon_holder').html('<div class="error_icon"></div>');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this so that you have access to the error_icon div after it is created:

```
var errorIcon = $('<div/>');
errorIcon.addClass('error_icon');
$('#error_icon_holder').append(errorIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on that patrick offered, `.append()` will preserve any existing content within the `error_icon_holder` div. If you would like to replace the contents entirely, use `.html()`.

If you don't want to include the `error_icon` class with the inner div creation statement you'll need two separate statements, one to create the inner div within the DOM tree and another to add the class to the newly created element.